# Unresolved constraint in bundle spring-plugin-core [78]: Execution environment not supported: J2SE-1.6

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, osgi

I'm trying to use springfox for Swagger documentation in my project. And I see that springfox is using 'maven-plugin'. And 'maven-plugin' is using 'maven-compiler-plugin' it is configured for jdk 1.6. But I'm using jdk 1.8. Because of this, when I deploy my war file in tomcat, I'm getting this error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle spring-plugin-core [78]: Execution environment not supported: J2SE-1.6
```

(FYI we are using Osgi for managing the bundles). Please help me fix this error.

> my pom.xml:

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

> 'spring-plugin' pom.xml: (This in build > plugins )

```html
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.6</source>
    <target>1.6</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is there any way to override this? If you need any more info please do ask. Thanks!

> Edit: I found out the problem i.e. there's no environment called 'J2SE-1.6'. It should be JavaSE-1.6. But I don't know how to override it.

Comment: It looks like your OSGi framework is misconfigured. Java 8 is backwards compatible with Java 6 so it should run that bundle just fine.

Comment: @Neil Yes, you are correct. I found out the problem i.e. there's no environment called 'J2SE-1.6'. It should be JavaSE-1.6. But I don't know how to override it. Please help me.